# Anomaly Detection Algorithms for one feature

Tags: csv, scikit-learn, anomaly-detection

I want to start simple and just try to find anomalies in a certain column of a csv file.
The anomalies have been added manually to the dataset, as a way to check how good different algorithms are performing.

Reading some articles, I found the these might be some good approaches.

- K-Means
- 3 Sigma

I am asking for any other algorithm or method that you would use to detect anomalies on a single column.

Comment: You need to start with a definition what an anomaly is. Methods will follow.

Comment: @Sergey Bushmanov, the anomalies will also be part of the research. I will take the maximum values and then mutiply t with a big number so there is really a difference between the normal numbers and the numbers that are added and need to play the role of anomalies

Comment: scikit-learn has a nice little array of them. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_anomaly_comparison.html